# Многопоточность и цикл for

Tags: c#, .net

Всем привет. Есть например N потоков, и есть цикл

```
for(int i = 0; i<=100; i++)
{
   //какие то действия
}
```

Как с делать лучше, чтобы каждый поток не начинался с 0.
 Т.е.

```
1поток = 0
2поток = 1
3поток = 2
Nпоток = N
```

Может я вообще не в ту сторону думаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В тот момент, когда вы порождаете некоторый поток, то вы можете передать ему некоторый набор аргументов. В вашем случае, очевидно, нужно потоку с номером `N` передать `N` как параметр.

*Как это происходит в C#, говоря о Thread и Thread Pool, можно посмотреть [**здесь.**](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/parameters.shtml)*

Answer (score 2):

Есть готовое решение для распараллеливания цикла `For`

```
    // A basic matrix multiplication.
    // Parallelize the outer loop to partition the source array by rows.
    Parallel.For(0, matARows, i =>
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matBCols; j++)
        {
            // Use a temporary to improve parallel performance.
            double temp = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < matACols; k++)
            {
                temp += matA[i, k] * matB[k, j];
            }
            result[i, j] = temp;
        }
    }); // Parallel.For
```

[Практическое руководство. Написание простого цикла Parallel.For](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460713.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

> Может я вообще не в ту сторону думаю?

Все сильно зависит от того, что вы хотите получить. Следует помнить, что поток - это довольно дорогой ресурс операционной системы и его поддержка требует накладных расходов. Запускать одновременно работающих потоков сильно больше, чем ядер у процессора - почти наверняка будет медленнее, чем просто последовательное выполнение.

Что касается исходного вопроса - то в функцию создания потока можно передать параметр, который будет доступен в функции потока.

```
Thread newThread = new Thread(Work.DoWork);
newThread.Start(42);
public static void DoWork(object data)
{
   var IntVal = (int)data;
}
```

подробности можно посмотреть в [документации](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6x4c42hc.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Я бы рекомендовал использовать расширяющий метод `AsParallel`.